# Не могу получить всё, что нужно

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

Я получил все топики, которые относятся к указанному форуму следующим путём:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int forumId)
{
    Forum forum = await _dbContext.Forum.SingleOrDefaultAsync(f => f.Id == forumId);
    if (forum == null)
        return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied", "Error");

    IEnumerable<Topic> topics = await _dbContext.Topic.Include("Owner")
        .Where(t => t.ForumId == forumId && t.Id == t.RootTopicId)
        .OrderByDescending(t => t.PostDateTime).ToListAsync();

    ViewBag.ForumId = forum.Id;
    ViewBag.ForumName = _dbContext.Forum.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Id == forumId).Name;

    return View(topics);
}
```

Теперь хочу получить последних отписавшихся. Думал как-то таким путём, но получаю не последних отписавшихся, а авторов...

```
var last = await _dbContext.Topic
                         .Where(t => t.ForumId == forumId && t.Id == t.RootTopicId)
                         .OrderBy(t => t.PostDateTime != DateTime.MaxValue).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Класс `Topic`:

```
public partial class Topic
{
    public Topic()
    {
        InverseReplyToTopic = new HashSet<Topic>();
        InverseRootTopic = new HashSet<Topic>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? OwnerId { get; set; }
    public int ForumId { get; set; }
    public int? RootTopicId { get; set; }
    public int? ReplyToTopicId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostDateTime { get; set; }
    public int? ModifiedByUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifyDateTime { get; set; }
    public bool IsLocked { get; set; }

    public Forum Forum { get; set; }
    public User ModifiedByUser { get; set; }
    public User Owner { get; set; }
    public Topic ReplyToTopic { get; set; }
    public Topic RootTopic { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Topic> InverseReplyToTopic { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Topic> InverseRootTopic { get; set; }
}
```

Класс `User`:

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Forum = new HashSet<Forum>();
        MessageFromUser = new HashSet<Message>();
        MessageToUser = new HashSet<Message>();
        TopicModifiedByUser = new HashSet<Topic>();
        TopicOwner = new HashSet<Topic>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }       
    public bool IsAdministrator { get; set; }
    public bool IsLocked { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegisterDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLoginDateTime { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Forum> Forum { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Message> MessageFromUser { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Message> MessageToUser { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Topic> TopicModifiedByUser { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Topic> TopicOwner { get; set; }
}
```

Класс `Forum`:

```
public partial class Forum
{
    public Forum()
    {
        Topic = new HashSet<Topic>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDateTime { get; set; }
    public bool IsLocked { get; set; }

    public User Owner { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Topic> Topic { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Скриншот таблицы с тестовыми записями:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Дополню: Тут хочу получить того, кто оставил последнее сообщение и дату:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    IEnumerable<Category> categories = await _dbContext.Category
        .Include(c => c.Forum)
        .OrderBy((Category cat) => cat.Id)
        .ToListAsync();

    foreach (var cat in categories)
        cat.Forum = cat.Forum.OrderBy(forum => forum.Id).ToList();

    var last = await _dbContext.Topic.Where(tx => tx.RootTopicId == 1).OrderByDescending(tx => tx.PostDateTime == DateTime.MaxValue).ToListAsync();

    ViewBag.Last = last.FirstOrDefault().OwnerId;

    return View(categories);
}
```

Comment: Что то я не пойму, а что вам нужно то? Какой раздел и из какой таблицы?

Comment: Добрый вечер @EvgeniyZ. У меня в данный момент 2 схожие задачи: Нужно получить последнего по времени автора (OwnerId в Topic). Ну и хочу подцепить во ViewBag. Сам то запрос рабочий. Он сортирует топики в категориях, а вот как к каждому топику вывести автора последнего сообщения - я пока не пойму. И в категориях планирую сделать что-то аналогичное (в шапку прикрепил так же действующий код)

Comment: Что то у вас не состыковывается тут. Допустим на скрине у вас нету `public User Owner { get; set; }`, а в классе есть. Так почему не доставать из `Owner`? Ведь он содержит полную информацию о пользователе. Ну или... Делайте поиск по пользователям и через `.Select` формируйте нужный вид.